# Conflicting declaration ‘typedef int RETCODE’ error when using FreeTDS libraries

Tags: c++, freetds, unixodbc

Am using FreeTDS libraries in order connect c++ to MSSQL, and am getting the below error on compilation.

> In file included from pa_main.cpp:16:0:
>   /usr/local/include/sybdb.h:120:13: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef int RETCODE’
>    typedef int RETCODE;
>
> In file included from /usr/include/sql.h:19:0,
>                    from pa_sql_db.h:16,
>                    from pa_main.cpp:11:
>   /usr/include/sqltypes.h:268:33: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef short int RETCODE’
>    typedef signed short            RETCODE;

What i understood is that unixodbc and freeTDS libraries using the same definition name RETCODE for different size int.

How can i avoid this situation ? Can anyone please suggest a workaround for this issue ?

Comment: Ugh, sounds like no-namespace conflicts. Good luck with that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're dealing with two libraries that have backwards compatibility with C. C doesn't have namespaces, so they pollute the global namespace with their `typedef`s. I would recommend keeping your code for each library in separate translation units.

Comment: I really appreciate your advise. Can you please provide a sample?

Comment: Your advise really helped me. I have separated the libraries in to two translation units and now its working nice.